# Ajax не работает на старой версии jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Вообщем, есть сайт с кучей вещей, которые используют 
`jquery.min.js(jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.4)`

И есть ajax запрос, который работает на jQuery 1.8.0, но не работает на 1.4.4 (почему, я не знаю, не шарю в этом). Помогите его под 1.4.4 переделать.

Вот скрипт:

```
function selectModel(Obj) {
    var auto = Obj.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/ajaxbase/modelcheckbox",
        data: {
            auto: auto
        },
        /*dataType: "json",*/
        cache: false,
        success: function (responce) {
            $('div[name="model_panel"]').html(responce);
        }
    });
};
```

**UPD**  Нашел опечатку в файле ajax/ajaxbase/modelcheckbox Исправил, но теперь ошибка следующая

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input         http://127.0.0.6/:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: selectModel is not defined   http://127.0.0.6/:468
```

Строка 1: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Строка 468: `<li><input type='checkbox' name='auto[]' id='auto1' value='Acura' onclick='javascript:selectModel(this);'/><label for='auto1' >Acura</label></li>`

**UPD2** Проблема решена, upd1 возник из-за случайно стертой закрывающейся фигурной скобки

Answer (score 2):

```
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Ну дык причем тут ajax запрос и Jquery? если ошибка на сервере 500!

```
var auto = Obj.value; // переменная auto
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/ajaxbase/modelcheckbox",
        data: {
            auto: auto // и тут тоже самое
        },
```

попробуй изменит на

```
var auto = Obj.value; // переменная auto
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/ajaxbase/modelcheckbox",
        data: {
            a: auto 
        },
```

Может ему это не нравится, да и вообще передавать название переменной таким же именем как и переменная, как-то глупо. на то они и переменные, чтобы отличать что передается от того  как получить значение

Comment: я тоже так сначала подумал, но ТС утверждает, что с 1.8 таких проблем нету

>передавать название переменной таким же именем как и переменная, как-то глупо 

странное заявление

Comment: нет я в плане того нет ли конфликта, что передаваемая переменная auto а выше они объявлена как var auto = Obj.value;


Нет может быть на мне пятница сказывается и то что скоро домой, пора завязывать работать на этой неделе :)

Ну как может не работать скрипт, если ошибка на сервере!

Comment: нет, конфликта быть не может:

    var auto = 'text';
    var obj = {auto: auto};
    obj //{auto : "text"}

Comment: значит я был прав!